# Cannot find symbol: getmodel()

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jlist

I would like to insert data into sql from JList. However, the getModel() at ListModel is stating that "cannot find symbol"

This is the action when the next button from previous form is clicked:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:


    DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();
    System.out.println(""+songsdetails.get(0));
    for(int i=0; i <songsdetails.size();i++){
        list.addElement(songsdetails.get(i));
    }
    jList1.setModel(list);


}                 



        }
```

This is the code for current form:

```
private void jButtonNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sdmusic","root","");

            st=cn.prepareStatement("INSERT `Username`, `SongsSelection` FROM `user` WHERE `Username`=?  'SongsSelection' = ?");


            ListModel model = list.getModel();
            for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
            System.out.println(model.getElementAt(i));
            }
```

Comment: What is the stackTrace of the exception?

Comment: @YassinHajaj auto creation from the Netbeans

Comment: @YassinHajaj Compiler errors don't have a stacktrace.

Comment: Please read the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) to know which methods are available. `getModel` is non of them.

Comment: @Tom Indeed but if he had tried to execute the code, he would have had the answer immediately within the stackTrace `The method getModel() is undefined for the type DefaultListModel`

Comment: @YassinHajaj His compiler is telling him that already with "cannot find symbol" :P.

Comment: @Tom Which does not seem clear to me but whatever :D You're right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 0):

> `DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();`

`list` is already set to `DefaultListModel`. You can't get ListModel of a ListModel.

What you might be looking for is:

```
DefaultListModel list = (DefaultListModel) jList1.getModel();
```